# Getting error : when set debugger in Nightwatchjs

Tags: node.js, debugging, nightwatch.js

Hi everyone I want to set debugger in my Nightwatchjs project But I got one error

[image]

my package.json

```
{
  "name": "intro-to-nightwatchjs",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "debug": "node --inspect-brk node_modules/.bin/nightwatch",
    "test": "nightwatch"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "chromedriver": "^80.0.1",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "minimist": "^1.2.5",
    "nightwatch": "^1.3.4",
    "optimist": "^0.6.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: are you sure the first error is not because you missed closing braces?

Comment: When I run my test its work properly but when I run debugger I am getting error and the file in which error show is a built in node module